# launching existing exe in a browser or xbap

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xbap

I have a application(exe1 for example) at the moment which is provided by our supplier of instruments and I would like to embed this exe1 into my current application.  I was thinking more like a xbap which will open up exe1 and when my application close exe1 disposes.

Has anyone got any ideas? I do not want to re-write the exe1 as it will be more like reinventing the wheel.

Some sort of remote viewer perhaps, run this application on different machine and show it in this viewer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "or active x" ... if the horse is dead, stop riding it.

Comment: fair comment. Thank you.

Comment: But seriously: Does that manufacturer perhaps also publish a library you could use instead of the exe? Would be way more convenient.

Comment: I have enquired and they do not have any library.  I asked for a API and they said what is a API :(

Comment: Oh, shoot ... what kind of "instrument" are we talking about? Like a music instrument or measurement instrument or a robot ... ? That sounds like they outsourced the development of the software.

Comment: You are probably right. It is a Robot.

Comment: Oh boy. A robot with an exe only ... did you have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: I have looked into process class.  It was thought to include a button of some sort which will launch this application however our application is a ISO Blah blah compliant (as per the standards our application has to be fullscreen etc) hence cannot loose focus onto another application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152754/discussion-between-fildor-and-abe).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response.  I have figured out that, the way to achieve this is to

1. Setup another machine (VM) will be running 24/7
2. Setup exe1 as startup application on the VM
3. This machine will start when the main application machine will start
4. The main application machine will have a VNC Viewer which will view the exe1 machine.
5. Install a lockdown tool to run the exe1 as fullscreen and disable windows combinations.

Thanks once again folks.